# Oozie - Run workflow by command line with configuration file in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hdfs, oozie

as a newbie with Oozie, I tried to run some tutorials by command line. My stepByStep:

- upload my Oozie project (workflow xml file, job.properties file, jar and data) to HDFS via HUE interface. In my job.properties files, I've indicated every information like data name node, path to my application, ...
- running via HUE interface, simply, I check on check box of workflow xml file and submit

I would like to run my Oozie project by command line:

- with job.properties file in local, I run: 
  oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run

How can I run my Oozie project instead of with the job.properties in local (instead of the config file in local, I want to run my job with the configuration file in HDFS)?

Thanks for any suggestion and feel free to comment if my question is not clear!

Comment: did you try giving the config param the hdfs path ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a direct way, but you certainly could do something like

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config <(hdfs dfs -cat examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties) -run
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but Oozie accepts only.properties or xml file. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: configuration must be a '.properties' or a '.xml' file

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: configuration must be a '.properties' or a '.xml' file
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.getConfiguration(OozieCLI.java:814)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.jobCommand(OozieCLI.java:963)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.processCommand(OozieCLI.java:673)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.run(OozieCLI.java:626)
        at org.apache.oozie.cli.OozieCLI.main(OozieCLI.java:225)
configuration must be a '.properties' or a '.xml' file

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware that oozie checks the file extension. Then I don't see another way then just downloading the file at least temporarily to the local filesystem. Or use something like [fuse-dfs](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS)